# NGINX reverse proxy based on the parameter

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I want to do reverse proxy in nginx using the parameter.URL shown like this. https://aaa.com/uploads/attachment1/aaa.pdf. "aaa.pdf" value dynanamically change.

I wont to do reverse proxy to the exeternal server.Ex: When the client calls "https://aaa.com/uploads/attachment1/aaa.pdf", It should be go to the https://192.168.251.10/uploads/attachment1/aaa.pdf using reverse proxy. How can I do that? Please help me.I did like this. But not worked for me.

```
 location /uploads/attachment1(/?)(.*)$ {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.251.10/uploads/attachment1/$;
}
```

Comment: There are no parameters, just a URL which is passed upstream unmodified. Try: `location /uploads/ { proxy_pass http://192.168.251.10; }`